# Is it okay for a foreign key to reference an identity field?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Suppose I have the following models in the ASP.NET MVC code first approach :

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}
```

That means I have a table called `City` Which has :

- Id ( Primary key and it's an identity field)
- Name ( varchar )

And another table called `Restaurant` Which has :

- Id ( Primary key and it's an identity field)
- CityId( Foreign key refrencing Id in `City` table and no cascade on delete )

Now because my city data is fixed and not changing much i use the seed method to populate it like:

```
context.Cities.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Name,
               new City() { Name = "Springfield" },
               new City() { Name = "Franklin" },
               new City() { Name = "Greenville" }
            );
```

Please notice I'm not assigning any ID because City Id is an identity field and auto-increments.

#### One Scenario:

A scenario which i fear is this:
Assume there are some restaurants in the `Restaurant` table referencing these cities. Now as time goes by, for some unknown reasons `Franklin` which had the Id of 2 gets deleted from the `City` table. So when you notice what happened, you insert `Franklin` as a city again but this time it's Id has changed. So what happens to those restaurants which were already referencing "Franklin" as their city?

Should I make City Id not an identity primary key but just an integer primary key and assign City Ids myself?

If I enable cascade delete on the foreign key, then i will lose the records referencing the deleted city and I don't want that. I want to keep them until I figure out what happened to the deleted city and fix the issue.

### Question

So with this information, in my case, is it a good practice to make a foreign key from an identity field? What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Whether or not a column is of type identity or not is irrelevant. The primary and foreign keys are used to reference related tables. If you delete a referenced value in a primary table such as City then you will get an error. You would first have to delete all records that reference that cities foreign key value. If later you add the city again then it would have a new id since you are using an identity column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primary and Foreign keys ensure something called "referential integrity." Just like it sounds, they ensure the integrity of the references contained in the data. If you have restaurants in a city you should not be allowed to delete that city because it would destroy the integrity of the references (i.e. you now have orphaned restaurants). The alternative would be to allow the database to delete the restaurants if you delete the city. Either of those scenarios (blocking the deletion or cascading the deletion) can be accomplished with a foreign key.

Whenever the data in one table is dependent on the data in another table for its existence you should create a foreign key to ensure you don't end up with data corruption. The fact that it is an identity column is irrelevant.

Your database is the last line of defense against corrupt data. You want to ensure that those "unknown reasons" that cause the row to be deleted are simply not allowed. It's easier to prevent the problem in the first place than to try to fix the data after it's corrupt.

Comment: It's important to distinguish between "foreign key", which is a concept in relational database design, and "foreign key constraint" which is a type of constraint that can be implemented on the columns of a table in SQL Server that enforces the relationship between the data in the foreign keys column(s) and the rows in the related table. *The existence of foreign key columns in a database model does not enforce referential integrity* - this can only be done by implementing the appropriate constraints on the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You woun't be able to delete any city from the table as long as there are restaurants referencing it.

That will be enforced by the foreign key. (You can customize this when creating the foreign key: ON DELETE CASCADE, ON DELETE SET NULL...)

So the answer is yes: it is a good practice.